# Is the lambda concurrent execution monitor "inaccurate"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

I wrote a simple python test, that calls a lambda behind an API gateway in a loop.

```
for doc in docs:
  payload = json.dumps({})
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
  response = requests.request("POST", f"https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs", headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I expect that the "Concurrent executions" monitor shows a constant value "1". But what I get is sometimes a "2":

[image]

Does anyone know why? Does AWS Cloudwatch only query the difference between "START" and "END" logs in a specific timeframe?

Comment: What is the reserved concurrency of yr lambda? If it's more than 1, then it's conceivable that the previous lambda execution was not cleaned up yet and it appears in the count. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

Comment: The reserved concurrency is currently at 10. I as well checked the logs in cloudwatch and there are no overlapping timespans. As you said, maybe AWS uses other timestamps like lambda execution environment start and end.

Comment: To achieve serial execution i would set concurrency to 1. I'm not sure what the concurrency of yr screenshot actually means. Does your code really run concurrently?

Comment: No, my code does not run concurrently. It is a strict serial execution. The loop only continues in case it receives a response (after lambda completion). So that was exactly why my expectation was, that the monitor should be at 1 all the time.

Comment: Agreed. The api you are using is blocking.

Comment: Could it happen that you have a call before your previous lambda execution ends completely ? If yes, lambda won't wait for your previous call to be complete and it will start parallely a new execution, so a new concurrency. It could be a reason why you have sometimes two concurrencies.

Comment: @jlh91 No, it is a strict serial execution.